# Accessing unpublished group content

Tags: organic-groups, users

I am using organic groups and I want the owner/reviewer of the group to be able to access an unpublished group content created by members of the group.

I know I can give "View any unpublished content" rights to a global user role, but this will be to strong (I have different reviewers for different groups and single reviewer should not have access to unpublished content of all the groups).

I want to give that right to the specific role in the group and "Organic groups global permissions" simply does not have that option.

I am familiar with hooks system but I am not sure how to approach the issue.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can add your own hook_permission (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) , where input parameter will be id of group(gid) and user id (uid), then check if user (uid) is group administer (gid) and return true if yes

Comment: Gaydabura thanks for the hint. I have found that there is a coresponding hook in the OG module hook_og_permission. I will still have to write some code but I can use http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/og_field_access_og_permission/7 as an example so it should be simple enough.

Comment: it is even better. good luck

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this example implementation which creates a new OG Permission **View unpublished content** and uses Node Grants to decide who can view unpublished nodes. You now can configure which OG Role in your groups are allowed to view unpublished nodes.

```
<?php
define('MY_MODULE_REALM_VIEW_UNPUBLISHED', 'my_module_view_unpublished');

/**
 * Implements hook_og_permission().
 */
function my_module_og_permission() {
  // Add OG permission to view unpublished nodes.
  return array(
    'view unpublished' => array(
      'title' => t('View unpublished content'),
      'description' => t("Allow user to see unpublished content within the group."),
      // Determine to which roles the permissions will be enabled by default.
      'default role' => array(OG_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_grants().
 */
function my_module_node_grants($account, $op) {
  if ($op != 'view') {
    return;
  }

  $grants = array();

  // Handle access to unpublished nodes.
  // Get all OG Group IDs the user is allowed to view unpublished nodes in.
  $entities = og_get_entity_groups();
  foreach ($entities['node'] as $entity_id) {
    if (og_user_access('node', $entity_id, 'view unpublished')) {
      $grants[MY_MODULE_REALM_VIEW_UNPUBLISHED][] = $entity_id;
    }
  }

  return $grants;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_access_records().
 */
function my_module_node_access_records($node) {
  // Node is unpublished and belongs to a OG group.
  if (!(empty($node->status) && $groups = og_get_entity_groups('node', $node))) {
    return array();
  }

  foreach ($groups['node'] as $nid) {
    $grants[] = array(
      'realm' => MY_MODULE_REALM_VIEW_UNPUBLISHED,
      'gid' => $nid,
      'grant_view' => 1,
      'grant_update' => 0,
      'grant_delete' => 0,
      'priority' => 10,
    );
  }
  return $grants;
}
```

Comment: To add this no longer works very well. I have implemented this and found that when the user goes to log into the site, it times out because they are not added to the primary/default group. Once I add them, then they can log in but this isn't ideal as we want them to only be added to their specific group.